# PHP String (maybe string indexing) with square bracket

Tags: php, string, indexing

I have been working with PHP for a few months and I have just come-up to the following, I have tried searching online but there is nothing I can find to explain how this works. Can some please explain how this works?

```
$s = '13149';  Original 
echo $s[$s[1]]; the indexed string in side another set of square brackets.
```

index 0 gives 3
index 1 gives 4
index 2 gives 3 again
index 3 gives 9
index 4 gives the following error:

> Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 9 in D:\xamp\htdocs\test.php on line 5

Comment: You can use an index on a string and it will return the character at that position. Think of a string as an array of characters and you'll get the idea. Here, `$s[1]` is used to get a character, and since they're all numeric, that value is again used as an offset for the same string, producing the result you've presented. You can find more in the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's definitely very confusing looking straight at it, but if you break it down, you can see what's happening. The inner index pulls another number out of the string, which becomes the new index of the string.

```
echo "0 of 13149 becomes index {$s[0]} which is {$s[$s[0]]}\n";
echo "1 of 13149 becomes index  {$s[1]} which is {$s[$s[1]]}\n";
echo "2 of 13149 becomes index  {$s[2]} which is {$s[$s[2]]}\n";
echo "3 of 13149 becomes index  {$s[3]} which is {$s[$s[3]]}\n";
echo "4 of 13149 becomes index  {$s[4]} which is {$s[$s[4]]}\n";

0 of 13149 becomes index  1 which is 3 
1 of 13149 becomes index  3 which is 4
2 of 13149 becomes index  1 which is 3
3 of 13149 becomes index  4 which is 9
```

Since there's only 5 numbers in the string, with indexes 0-4, index 9 does not exist.

Comment: how can you access the two "1"s in the string?

Comment: Well, the first 1 is at index (position) 0, the second is at index (position) 2. This means that `$s[0]` and `$s[2]` reference the number 1. The second attempt at indexing (the outer `$s`) will get the number at index (position) 1, which is the number 3.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, analysing your responses and figuring out that the actual numbers within the string causes the given output is all I needed to hopefully manage this issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the desired result as below

```
$s = '13149';

    echo $s[0];
    echo $s[1];
    echo $s[2];
    echo $s[3];
    echo $s[4];
```

A more detail was answered by @El_Vanja see first comment.

Comment: of course you are right with that, but I am preparing for an exam that is going to have one or two question with something like $s[$s[1]] = $s[1] + $s[3]; and I want to be able to workout the answer: